# Edit form returns null value Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have an Edit Form in my application and when tries to save (insert) the new record I get this error message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO in_orden_compra_detalle (id_orden_compra, id_producto, cantidad, precio_compra, total, entrega, fecha_entrega) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, 89, 45, null, null, null]:
```

Table in_orden_compra_detalle is related to 2 tables (in_producto and in_orden_compra)

Here my relatioship:

```
class InOrdenCompra
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InProveedor", inversedBy="InOrdenCompra")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_proveedor", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $proveedorOc;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nival\AccesoBundle\Entity\AdUsuario", inversedBy="InOrdenCompra")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_usuario", referencedColumnName="id_usuario")
     */
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InOrdenCompraDetalle", mappedBy="InOrdenCompra", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $ordenCompra;



class InProducto
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InOrdenCompraDetalle", mappedBy="InProducto", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $productoOc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productoOc = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }


class InOrdenCompraDetalle
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InOrdenCompra", inversedBy="InOrdenCompraDetalle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_orden_compra", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $ordenCompra;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InProducto", inversedBy="InOrdenCompraDetalle")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_producto", referencedColumnName="id_producto")
     */
    protected $productoOc;
```

My Controller for new record:

```
public function newAction($id_orden_compra)
    {
        $entity = new InOrdenCompraDetalle();

        $entity->setOrdenCompra($this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompra')->find($id_orden_compra));

        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $id_orden_compra);

        return $this->render('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompraDetalle:new.html.twig', array(
            'id_orden_compra' => $id_orden_compra,
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I need to pass the id_orden_compra value to setOrdenCompra in entity InOrdenCompraDetalle.

Also id_producto should have the value selected from entity field:

```
->add('productoOc', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'NivalInventarioBundle:InProducto',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($displayname) {
                                return $displayname->getDisplayName();},
            'by_reference' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opción',
            'mapped' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
        ))
        ->add('cantidad')
        ->add('precioCompra')
```

But also comes null.

Please help

UPDATED

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $id_orden_compra)
    {
        $entity = new InOrdenCompraDetalle();

        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $id_orden_compra);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('inordencompradetalle_show', array('id_orden_compra' => $id_orden_compra, 'id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompraDetalle:new.html.twig', array(
            'id_orden_compra' => $id_orden_compra,
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

createCreateForm:

```
private function createCreateForm(InOrdenCompraDetalle $entity, $id_orden_compra)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new InOrdenCompraDetalleType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('inordencompradetalle_create', array('id_orden_compra' => $id_orden_compra)),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: You make sure that `id_orden_compra, id_producto, total, entrega, fecha_entrega` columns can be nullable?

Comment: They cant, except fecha_entrega and entrega. id_orden_compra should come with value from $entity->setOrdenCompra($this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompra')->find($id_orden_compra)); and id_producto should have a value from edit form, because user selects from an entity field (select from table InProducto)

Comment: I don't see where is the `persist` and `flush` methods in your controller? Where you save this entity?

Comment: I updated my post with code.

Comment: `$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $id_orden_compra);` ? It's a custom method in your controller ?

Comment: I was generated by CRUD of Symfony.
I updated the post.

Comment: How do you use constraints validation for this entity? http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html, this would prevent your data are in invalid state and prevent also save them incorrecty. See `NotBlank` constraints.